# Does Axton's Sabre Turret allow for legendary drops?

Tags: borderlands-2

When I'm farming for legendaries as Axton, is it a bad idea to let my sabre turrets kill the enemy? Do I need to kill them myself to allow a legendary to drop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

The idea that killing things with your action skill would reduce the legendary drop rate seemed so absurd initially that I almost downvoted the question. I mean, depending on your build, that could easily be the main way you kill everything. It would be extremely odd to penalize a large segment of players playing the game the way it was intended.

That being said, whether you or your follower kills something in Diablo 2 can have an impact on the magic find rate in certain rare circumstances, so I decided it wasn't *completely* ludicrous.

After about 15 minutes searching [message boards](http://borderlands2forum.com/showthread.php?t=2382), [wikis](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Legendary), and [guides](http://www.gearboxsoftware.com/2013/09/inside-the-box-the-borderlands-2-loot-system/), I see no reason to think that you should avoid killing things with your turret.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... and for not down voting the question :)

Comment: Well, it's also not "_completely_ ludicrous" or "absurd" because the game says that the turret is a separate entity, but I like the point you made.

Comment: +1 For all the reasons above. It just doesn't make sense for the turret to have this effect. Or any of the characters action skills.